# JavaScript includes() and ignore no whitespace, fix code formatting

Tags: javascript, string, whitespace

I have a function that takes a **string** (specifically an address or postcode from an input) and then adds strong tags around matched results. It works fine but I would like it to match characters that **don't have whitespace**. For instance if the input string is `cf142` I would like it to match `CF14 2`.

Below is the function:

```js
emboldenMatch(string, query) {
  query = query.toLowerCase().trim();
  if (string.toLowerCase().includes(query)) {
    const queryLength = query.length;
    const matchIndex = string.toLowerCase().indexOf(query);
    const matchEnd = matchIndex + queryLength;
    const before = string.substr(0, matchIndex);
    const match = string.substr(matchIndex, queryLength);
    const after = string.substr(matchEnd, string.length - matchEnd);  

    return `${before}<strong>${match}</strong>${after}`;
  } else {
    return string;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can remove whitespaces using `query = query.toLowerCase().trim().replace(/\s+/g, '');`. Is that what you are looking for? (Explanation: .replace() is a function that replaces any character found using the first argument with the second argument. The first argument is a regex that matches all whitespace characters. The second argument is an empty string)

Comment: I think that might mess up the index position though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can write your exist function as following:

```js
 function emboldenMatch(string, query) {
    return string.replace(query, "<strong>$&</strong>")
}
console.log(em('some string with bold text', 'bold'));
```

If you want to wrap every match, and not only the first one, and be insensitive, you can make it a `regexp`, and add the `g` (=global) flag, and `i` (=insensitive) flag:

```js
function emboldenMatch(string, query) {
  return string.replace(new RegExp(escapeRegExp(query), 'gi'), "<strong>$&</strong>")
}
function escapeRegExp(string) {
  return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
}

console.log(emboldenMatch('some string with bold bold text', 'bold'));
```

Now, if you want to add an optional spaces in between characters, you can add it to the regexp as following:

```js
function emboldenMatch(string, query) {
    var reg = new RegExp(escapeRegExp(query).split('').join('\\s*'), 'gi');
    return string.replace(reg, "<strong>$&</strong>")
}
function escapeRegExp(string) {
  return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&');
}

console.log(emboldenMatch('some string with bo ld  b old text', 'bold'));
```

Comment: OPs question indicates they want case-insensitive matches so add the `i` flag 

Comment: Now that is a thing of beauty. Thanks!

Comment: @YosefTukachinsky Could you assist in allowing matches that don't include a comma in the query but do include a comma in the string? Thanks

Comment: @YosefTukachinsky could you help on my last comment on ignoring commas also?

Comment: By using `.join('\\s*')` you ignored spaces, if you want to add comma to there - just add there. `.join('[\\s,]*')`

Comment: Thank you again for your assistance. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```js
function emboldenMatch(string, query) {
    query = query.toLowerCase().trim().replace(/ /g,'');
    if (string.toLowerCase().includes(query)) {
      const queryLength = query.length;
      const matchIndex = string.toLowerCase().indexOf(query);
      const matchEnd = matchIndex + queryLength;
      const before = string.substr(0, matchIndex);
      const match = string.substr(matchIndex, queryLength);
      const after = string.substr(matchEnd, string.length - matchEnd);  

      return `${before}<strong>${match}</strong>${after}`;
    } else {
      return string;
    }
  }
  
  console.log(emboldenMatch('asdf2', 'asdf 2'))
  console.log(emboldenMatch('asdf2', 'asdf2'))
```